# MSCAPI : CNG and Security Descriptors

Tags: security, cryptography, acl, cng, mscapi

The Windows API provides ways to set [**security descriptors**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379563(v=vs.85).aspx) on objects (allowing the setup of [*Access Control Lists*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374872(v=vs.85).aspx), for instance).

*Security Descriptors* of cryptographic keys hosted by a [*Key Storage Provider* (KSP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb931355%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be valued using the `NCryptSetProperty` (and the proper set of flags and parameters).

The [*Cryptography Provider Development Kit* (CPDK)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30688) doesn't require any mandatory support of *Security Descriptors* though (and on dedicated servers where no user account is created, it might not be useful to set an *Access Control List* indeed).

Does someone know if Security Descriptors support by KSP is expected by some Microsoft applications despite everything? (like Active Directory Certificate Services, for instance)